# Is it possible to nest folders in the Flash Builder bin-debug

Tags: apache-flex, flash, ant, flexbuilder

I'm trying to setup my bin-debug folder so that the structure looks like this:

- bin-debug

  - assets

    - img
    - swf

      - main.swf
  - css

    - style.css
  - js

    - swfobject.js
  - index.html

I've tried setting the project's output folder to: bin-debug/assets/swf which does get my main.swf where I want it, but then my other source folders get dumped into that swf folder as well. What I would really like is to tell Flash Builder to put my swf into a nested folder and to be able to specify where my build folders' output goes as well. Is this at all possible without resorting to ANT scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up setting up an Ant script to pull this off and completely removing the html-template folder. Doesn't seem like there's any decent alternative. The upshot is that the Ant script gives me a lot more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible in Flash Builder. I have been looking for this feature myself but with no luck. I know it is possible in FDT though.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the html-template folder to look like the structure of your desired output. The variables in the index.template.html file is pretty well [documented](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ba5.html) as well.

Comment: If I tell my project to publish to bin-debug/assets/swf it will dump the entire html template into the 'assets/swf' folder.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me a bit. The idea is that in html-template you create the directory structure that you want to have in your bin-debug folder. Think of it this way, basically what happens is that html-template is copied, renamed to bin-debug and any template files in that folder is processed. Then your swf files are compiled and put in there as well. It's not super-flexible, you can't pull things from other projects for instance, but that's where other tools like ant/maven/whatever comes in instead.

Comment: The issue that I'm having is that the swf files always end up in the root of html-template/bin-debug. I don't want them to end up there but as I see it there's no way to change that behavior. I understand how adding files to html-template carries over to bin-debug, but I don't see how to keep index.html in the root of bin-debug and place my default app swf in a subfolder. My only solution so far has been to use ANT

Comment: I see what you mean now. Yes, that's an unfortunate issue. As far as I know, Flash Builder will place the swf files in the same directory as the *.template.html files (whatever directory that may be), but I don't think it can separate them out of the box. The way I solved this before was to have my templates in the subdir I wanted the swf-files in, and then use a static index.html in the root. It works, but is not ideal, especially since you get useless html files scattered across the target.

Comment: If anyone is interested I can post the ant script that we use. It handles this functionality for bin-debug and bin-release

Comment: I am interested in the Ant script!